# Angular - Passing value from HTML to component does not work

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, data-binding

In my project I am trying to pass `name` from `.html` to `.ts` file.

In `.html` file I pass value to `newValue` method. In ts when I `console.log the value of name`, is `displays nothing`.

How can I make this work?

.ts

```
  newValue(name: string) {
  console.log(name); ------------------> displays nothing
  }
```

.html

```
  <dd id="{{genId(name.value)}}">
          <inline-concept-edit *ngIf="name.$new; else noValueExists" id="tane"
 [(field)]="name.value" [elementType]="record.finish"(fieldChange)="newValue(name)"></inline-concept-edit>
          <ng-template #noValueExists>
            <span *ngIf="!name.$new"
                  matTooltip="We cannot change the value"
                  [matTooltipPosition]="'right'"
                  [matTooltipDisabled]="!editMode">
              {{name.value}}
            </span>
          </ng-template>
        </dd>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please mentioned what is this *name*? The code pasted above do not show what reference *name* holds.
My guess *name* is not getting passed into that method when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0):

@Tejs Mehta. you must be emitting this value from `inline-cell-edit` component (I assume this is your custom component).

If yes try to console over there as well.

and change this line from

`(fieldChange)="newValue(name)"` to
`(fieldChange)="newValue($event)"`